# Apply a custom function to every row of a column in pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a function that takes keyword (string) as its input and output a tuple of string.

```
  cat=""
  lang=""
  en=""
  try:
    if keyword!=None or keyword != "" or keyword!="null":
      cat=df[df.isin([keyword]).any(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)['abc_category'][0]
      en=df[df.isin([keyword]).any(axis=1)].reset_index(drop=True)['keywords_in_english'][0]
      lang=df[df == keyword].dropna(how='all',axis=1).columns.to_list()[0]
  except:
    cat="null"
    lang="null"
    en="null"
  # return cat, en, lang
  return cat, en, lang
```

Originally, the function will be used like this:

```
out_gl_df['Category'], out_gl_df["Keyword_EN"] , out_gl_df["Language"]= zip(*out_gl_df["Keywords_ABC"].apply(get_category))
```

However since it took quite long to run in pandas, I've created a pyspark version of the function and apply like this:

```
def get_category_py(keyword,pdf=abc_keywords_df):
  cat=""
  lang=""
  en=""
  try:
    if keyword!=None or keyword != "" or keyword!="null":
      rows_w_kw = pdf.filter(F.coalesce(*[F.when(F.col(x).isin(keyword),F.lit(1)) for x in pdf.columns])==1)
      cat = rows_w_kw.select('abc_category').first()[0]
      en = rows_w_kw.select('keywords_in_english').first()[0]
      lang = [x for x in rows_w_kw.columns if rows_w_kw.filter(F.col(x) == keyword).count() > 0][0]
  except:
    cat="null"
    lang="null"
    en="null"
  return "-".join([cat, en, lang])

out_gl = out_gl.withColumn("Get_Cat", get_category_py(col('Keywords_ABC')))
```

But then there emerges this error: PySparkTypeError: [NOT_A_COLUMN] Argument `col` should be a Column, got str.

I've tried registering the function in pandas version as UDF but it's quite slow. Is there any other pandas-equivalent way to do this?